# Trimming in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
      function ShowEditBox(serial) 
    {

        $("#divEditBox").slideDown("medium");
        var pserial ='PName'+ serial;
        var colindex = 0;
        var $tr = $("#" + pserial).parent().parent();

        $tr.find('td').each(function () {

            if (colindex == 2) {
                $("#txtName").val($(this).text());

            } else if (colindex == 3) {
                $("#txtSurName").val($(this).text());

            } else if (colindex == 4) {
                $("#txtEmail").val($(this).text());

            } else if (colindex == 5) {

                $("#txtMobile").val($(this).text());
            } else if (colindex == 6) {

                $("#txtAddress").val($(this).text());
            }

            colindex++;


        })

        $("#hdField").val(serial);
    }
```

Whenever i click the edit button in grid view that particular row data should be displayed in text boxes. But here i am getting unnecessary spaces in text boxes.
How can i trim the spaces in the Text box(txtName) ?? I am getting spaces in text .

Comment: Did you search for "trim javascript" ?

Comment: [$.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript `trim()` method.

```
$("#txtName").val($(this).text().trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`$.trim("string")`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/),

```
 $("#txtName").val($.trim($(this).text()));
```

Answer (score 2):

use `trim()` function of javascript

for jquery look at here [Trim](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)
Look at here

example

```
var str = "         lots of spaces before and after         ";
$( "#original" ).html( "Original String: '" + str + "'" );
$( "#trimmed" ).html( "$.trim()'ed: '" + $.trim(str) + "'" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function ShowEditBox(serial) 
    {

        $("#divEditBox").slideDown("medium");
        var pserial ='PName'+ serial;
        var colindex = 0;
        var $tr = $("#" + pserial).parent().parent();

        $tr.find('td').each(function () {

            if (colindex == 2) {
                $("#txtName").val($.trim($(this).text()));

            } else if (colindex == 3) {
                $("#txtSurName").val($.trim($(this).text()));

            } else if (colindex == 4) {
                $("#txtEmail").val($.trim($(this).text()));

            } else if (colindex == 5) {

                $("#txtMobile").val($.trim($(this).text()));
            } else if (colindex == 6) {

                $("#txtAddress").val($.trim($(this).text()));
            }

            colindex++;


        })

        $("#hdField").val(serial);
    }
```